Reference request for analytical (non-convex) optimization with Hermitian variables
I'm having trouble finding references on non-convex optimization problems involving complex Hermitian variables. More specifically, given an optimization problem of this kind, I would like to learn (preferably with examples) how to find the dual problem, investigate whether or not strong duality holds, and derive the KKT conditions, where possible.
I'm relatively new to the world of optimization. I've read Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe and found it helpful, but I would like to focus more on problems with matrix rather than scalar variables and on non-convex problems. I'm also only interested in analytics rather than coding.
Failing this, I would also be interested in references on convex optimization with complex Hermitian variables.
